# Shark transitions over density of sensors

Tags: normalization

Perhaps this is a very simple question, and I apologize, but I have no intuition about how to solve it. The problem is the following:

I have a couple of thousand sensors in some sea area. The sensors are not uniformly distributed, they are way more dense (more sensors near each other) in some areas than in others. Now, we're measuring transition of sharks from one sensor to the next, but it stands to reason that there will be more transitions where there are more sensors (besides the fact that since the sensors are radio based, there will be some noise).

The question is: what would be the best way to normalize the readings of the transitions so that we can compare areas of higher density of sensors (and shark trips) versus lower density of sensors?

Comment: you need to explain what exactly are you measuring, and what are you trying to model

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to track the sharks.  Why not just do so, then, and create a time-stamped vector representation of their travels?  Could you explain the scientific meaning of the transitions?

Comment: Are you just trying to model the distribution/density of sharks across this 2D region? Or something else?